# failed in "sudo pip"

Tags: python, permissions, pip, sudo

Please help me.

- server : aws ec2
- os : amazon linux
- python version : 2.7.10

```
$ pip --version
pip 7.1.2 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

It's OK.
But...

```
$ sudo pip --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 5, in 
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3020, in 
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 616, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 629, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 807, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pip==6.1.1
```

Answer (score 24):

I had the same problem.

1. `sudo which pip`
2. `sudo vim /usr/bin/pip`
3. modify any `pip==6.1.1` to `pip==8.1.2` or the version you just upgrade to.

It works for me.

Comment: You may have to `sudo vim /usr/bin/pip-2.7` or `pip-3.5`

Answer (score 17):

Try this:

`sudo easy_install --upgrade pip`

By executing this you are upgrading the version of pip that sudoer is using.

Answer (score 2):

if you have 2 versions of pip for example /user/lib/pip and /user/local/lib/pip belongs to python 2.6 and 2.7. you can delete the /user/lib/pip and make a link pip=>/user/local/lib/pip.
you can see that the pip commands called from "pip" and "sudo" pip are different. make them consistence can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see with `sudo` you run another `pip` script.

With `sudo`: `/usr/bin/pip` which is older version;

Without `sudo`: `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip` which is the latest version.

The error you encountered is sometimes caused by using different package managers, common way to solve it is the one already proposed by @Ali:

`sudo easy_install --upgrade pip`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming two pip versions are present at /usr/bin/pip & /usr/local/bin/pip where first is present for sudo user & second for normal user. 
From sudo user you can run below command so it will use higher version of pip for installation.

> /usr/local/bin/pip install jupyter

Answer (score 0):

1. `pip --version`. Remember the version the pip. Will be useful later.
2. `sudo which pip`. The location should be something like /usr/bin/pip-2.7
3. `sudo nano /usr/bin/pip-2.7`
4. Within nano modify any `pip==6.1.1` to `pip==9.0.1` or the version you found with `--version`. There is not much text to change there.
5. `sudo cp /usr/bin/pip-2.7 /usr/bin/pip`. Copy this files to make the same.

I need to do this steps every time I upgrade pip. :(

For the upgrading of the pip you can use also the following call, was working for me:

```
sudo easy_install --upgrade pip.
```